# site not recognizing img alt tags

Tags: html, image, validation, alt

When [validating](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://zoparealty.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3) a site I received the following error attached to a number of images:

An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images.

This comes despite the fact that I have included alt tags in my code:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=7"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="about%20Z" /></a>
                <ul class="about">
                    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=35">ZR</a> |</li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=38"> RA</a> |</li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=40"> WM + SB</a> |</li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=42"> ZV</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end subs -->
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=16"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="ZB" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=13"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/share.png" alt="swZ" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=9"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="cZ" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.thezopateam.com/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/properties.png" alt="ZP" /></a>
                <ul class="properties">
                    <li><a href="http://www.thezopateam.com/">Buying</a> |</li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=46"> Selling</a></li>
                </ul><!-- end subs -->
            <li><a href="index.php?page_id=11"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/gallery.png" alt="Zg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this/how to remedy? Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what? Where are the `alt` tags?

Comment: right before the closing tags, ex: `alt="ZB" /></a></li>`

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you seem to be missing the `alt` attribute at first `<img>` inside `<a>`

```
<li>
   <a href="index.php?page_id=7">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"> <!-- Missing Alt Attribute -->
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="about%20Z" />
   </a>
...
```

There are around 6 `<img>` tags without the `alt` attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you check "Show Source" under "Options" and then click Revalidate, you will be able to see exactly where these issues are.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every `<img>` tag must have an `alt` attribute.  The validator should tell you exactly which images (which lines) are missing `alt` attributes.  Alt attributes provide context for the image for those who cannot see / parse images (think Google).

It's difficult to say for sure (since you've provided PHP, not HTML) but it looks like each of these `<img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">` is missing `alt` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The errors were not specifically relating to the lack of alt tags(because they were there), but instead triggered by errors in my php. 
Fixed the errors, page validates.